# If else condition in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm trying to loop thru if else condition where if they are current show the item and if not show the message that there are no items. The problem i am having is the message keeps showing no matter what. What am I doing incorrectly?

I've tried put the message outside of the loop completely and tried else if  (iscurrent=false) and in both instances the message still shows.

```
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            if (item.IsCurrent == true)
            {
                <li>
                    @item.Id
                </li>
            }
            else if (item.IsCurrent == false)
            { 
                @: There is not a current Item at this time. Do you want 
                to
                <a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Item" asp- 
            action="CreateItem"> add a Item?</a>
            }
        }




    </ul>

  </div>
```

I expect to only show the items that are set to IsCurrent only and when there are no items the message to show only.

Comment: Any assistance with this please would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would be closer to what you want:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
            @if (Model.Items.Any(x => x.IsCurrent))
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                {
                    if (item.IsCurrent)
                    {
                        <li>
                            @item.Id
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                @:There is not a current Item at this time. Do you want to
                <a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Item" asp-action="CreateItem">add a Item?</a>
            }
       </ul>
</div>
```

First it checks for any items that are current using `.Any()`, then loops through the `Model.Items` and displays the current ids. If not, it displays the no current item message.